# How to use scope in AR request with joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

In my case I have a model Product has_one Location

I use a geocoder gem to search location near a distance.

The request Location.near([0, 0], 100) is look like this:

> SELECT locations.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((0 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(0 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((1 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) AS distance, CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(longitude - 1), RADIANS(latitude - 0))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM \"locations\"  WHERE (6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((0 - locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(0 * PI() / 180) * COS(locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((1 - locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) )) <= 20) ORDER BY distance

I want to do something like this:

```
Product.where(...).joins(:location).dosomething
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

`Location#near` is a named scope? If so you can merge it with your `Product` scope using the `&` operator. I think this should work:

```rb
class Product
  scope :near, lambda { |coord, dist| joins(:location) & Location.near(coord, dist) }

  ...
end
```

Then you can just use it like so:

```
Product.near([0, 0], 100)
```

Comment: Yes, it is a scope. I tried it and have got a 3 queries: Proposal Load (5442.1ms)  SELECT "proposals".* FROM "proposals" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."locationable_id" = "proposals"."id" AND "locations"."locationable_type" = 'Proposal'
  Location Load (186.6ms)  SELECT locations.*, 6371.0 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((0 - locations.latitude) ...
  Proposal Load (4920.5ms)  SELECT "proposals".* FROM "proposals"

Comment: What is Proposal? And can you show the code for `Location#near`?

Comment: Proposal == Product. Location#near => https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/stores/active_record.rb#L34

Comment: Merging the scopes doesn't seem to work. It might have to do with `select` in the `near` scope. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, since merging the scopes doesn't seem to work:

```rb
class Product
  scope :near, lambda { |coord, dist| where(:id => Location.near(coord, dist).all.map(&:locationable_id) }

  ...
end
```

And usage like in the other answer:

```
Product.near([0, 0], 100)
```

Comment: sorry. this solution is not for production